# How do I cast a concatenated string to a Class.Property?

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

I have a static class with several static strings used to store constant values. For example, Foo.Bar might return a string representing database column name and Foo.Foo might return a string with an epoch value.

In my application, I need to concatenate the class name with the name of the string to get the value I need. For example, I know the class name is Foo. I also know the property name is Bar. However the property name changes based on another value. In a foreach, I'm concatenating the class name with the other property name to get a string "Foo.Bar". So far we're okay. When I pass the concatenated string into my method that takes a string, it does not retrieve the static string from the class. In other words, even though the concatenated string is formed correctly as "Foo.Bar", my method does not return the value of Foo.Bar. If I hardcode Foo.Bar I get the string I need but this really needs to be done a runtime.

Any thoughts on how I can fix this? Can I cast this to something?

```
public static class Foo
{
    public static string Bar = "Sample Text";
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {

     // string "Foo.Bar" is built here by combining two strings.

     ...
     // more processing
     ...

     // I need the literal value of Foo.Bar here not literally "Foo.Bar"...

     }
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what it is you just said. Can you provide some pseudo code showing what you're doing and/or wanting to do?

Comment: Yea, since it sounds like there's a specific problem you're having here, you need to post the code you're trying that's giving you this trouble.

Comment: It sounds like it might involve reflecting on Foo to find a method named Bar?

Comment: _"to store constant values"_ - can't you use resource files?

Answer (score 0):

If `Foo` is always the class, then you could just pass in the name of the property instead of the concatenated string:

```
public string GetString(string propertyName)
{
    return typeof(Foo).GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(null, null);
}
```

If it's not always `Foo`, you could pass in the type to the `GetString()` method also.

Answer (score 0):

Reflection...

Consider:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

You can do:

```
Foo a = new Foo() { Bar = "Hello!" };
MessageBox.Show(typeof(Foo).GetProperty("Bar").GetValue(a,null) as string);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use reflection. As an aside - note that reflection is slow(er), can lead to errors at runtime, doesn't respond to refactoring tools, etc. so you may want to rethink how you're doing things; eg., a `Dictionary<string, string>` seems like it'd be easier to manage.

For reflection, you'll need to get (a) the type since it seems you are referincing > 1 class, and then (b) the property. Something like:

```
var lookupKey = "Foo.Bar";
var typeName = lookupKey.Substring(0, lookupKey.LastIndexOf("."));
var propName = lookupKey.Substring(lookupKey.LastIndexOf(".") + 1);

var typeInfo = Type.GetType(typeName, true);
var propInfo = typeInfo.GetProperty(propName);

return propInfo.GetGetMethod().Invoke(null, null);
```